# Automation id's for python

Tags: python

I am completely new to Python.

We are at present using Test Complete for the purpose of our project automation.

Test complete internally has a spy tool which is used for fetching object id's which would be useful for automation.

I am now planning to use python for the same purpose. I would like to know if

1. Python has a tool for spying objects for fetching the object id's
   which can be used for automating, else can I use object ids fetched
   from another spy tool and use it in python?
2. Can I script with python in sikuli ide?
3. Once I get the automation id's what function should I use for python
   to recognise the object using id and click on that object on the
   screen?

Comment: What do you mean by "automation ids" or "object ids"? Do you mean e.g. the memory position of instances?

Comment: Unique ids assigned to objects not designed in Python

Comment: Using a spy tool, I can hover over any object of an application and fetch it's unique ID. Using this ID, I can perform functions like clicking on the object through my script and other functions. So how do I get these ids in Python. Else if I already have the ids using another tool, can I use the same ids to call that object in python ?

Comment: There is the `id` function in python. Is it that what you are looking for?

Comment: But the id function in python is used for recognising objects created in python right ? I am looking to control wpf objects by fetching their unique ids which I can then use to script in python ?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't get what you are asking for

Comment: I just had a look at pywinauto. I believe this add in can be used to control wpf control objects ?

Comment: Hi Ianguitar. I am really sorry if I am unable to express myself correctly. Maybe I could explain it better over a chat if you are fine with that